# Calculate car battery charge time given constant voltage

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, automotive

I just bought this 55 Ah AGM car battery https://www.costco.ca/energizer-35-agm-battery.product.100408225.html it is currently at 11.9 V. My car idles at approximately 13.6 V. How can I approximate how long the battery will take to charge?

Comment: You need to consider the power developed by the alternator - and they need to be rotating at sufficient spe3ed, which is why the driving ratio between the engine crank pulley and the alternator pulley is about 3:1 but that also is defined by the max speed of the engine and the design rev range. Apart from that just divide the energy needed to charge the battery by the rate of energy delivered - consider the losses as well.

Comment: @SolarMike is it possible to calculate the rate of charge/current given the battery starting voltage and charging voltage? Or must I buy a current measuring device to calculate current?

Comment: You need a measuring device. A car battery can supply 1A at 11.5V or 500A at 11.5V.

Comment: Depends on the alternator but probably 1 hour or more. At 13.6 V, your battery will never be fully charged. Ideally, use a (smart) charger and charge it up to 14.4-14.6 V initially.

Comment: _"I just bought this 55 Ah AGM car battery... it is currently at 11.9 V."_ - that's not good.  https://workshoppist.com/agm-battery-state-of-charge/